# Прижатый к низу footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

День добрый, есть макет, в котором готово все, кроме футера.

Пробовал разными способами, но ничего не получалось, футер отображался только внизу обозреваемого поля страницы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(Черным является footer)

Хотя, ниже есть еще контент. Как я узнал, устанавливая `height: 100%` для `html, body`, они имеют высоту `500px`. Поэтому именно на таком расстоянии и отображается `footer`.

В этом деле я еще молод, мало понимаю.

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 background: white;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

img{
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.container{
 width: 99%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

header{
 display: inline-block;
 background: #2f3640 no-repeat center top / cover;
 width: 100%;
}
aside{
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
}
section{
 min-height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.content{
 height: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}
footer{
 padding-top: 50px;
 background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="content">
  <header class="clearfix">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="/"><img class="logo" src="img/logo6.png"></a>   
      <ul class="menu">
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Что ищем?">
          <button type="submit"></button>
        </form>
        <ul class="signlogin">
          <li><a href="#">Регистрация</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Авторизация</a></li>      
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <aside>
        <ul class="catalog">
          <li><a href="catalog/osnov-complect.html">Основные комплектующие</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalog/hranenie-dannyh.html">Хранение данных</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalog/ustroistva-rashireniya.html">Устройства расширения и апгрейд</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalog/systemi-ohl.html">Системы охлаждения</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalog/komp-system.html">Компьютерные системы</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalog/periferiya.html">Периферия</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalog/programmnoe-obesbechenie.html">Программное обеспечение</a></li>
          <li><a href="catalog/accessories.html">Аксессуары</a></li>    
        </ul>
        <ul class="news">
          // тут новости
        </ul>
      </aside>
      <div class="rec-catalog">
        <p>Рекомендуемые Вам товары</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="products">
        //тут у меня продукты
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>
  <p>Подвал 2018</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Вы пытались смотреть примеры bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer/?

Answer (score 0):

Сброс стилей от Эрика Майера

```css
/* Eric Meyer's CSS Reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/* End of Eric Meyer's CSS Reset */

html {
 height: 100%;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
 display: block;
}
body {
 font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
 height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
 min-width: 500px;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.header {
 height: 150px;
 background: #FFE680;
}


/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.content {
 padding: 0 0 100px;
}




/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.footer {
 margin: -100px auto 0;
 min-width: 500px;
 max-width: 1000px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #BFF08E;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
 <title></title>
 <meta name="keywords" content="" />
 <meta name="description" content="" />
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

 <header class="header">
  <strong>Header:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tortor. Praesent dictum, libero ut tempus dictum, neque eros elementum mauris, quis mollis arcu velit ac diam. Etiam neque. Quisque nec turpis. Aliquam arcu nulla, dictum et, lacinia a, mollis in, ante. Sed eu felis in elit tempor venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut ultricies porttitor purus. Proin non tellus at ligula fringilla tristique. Fusce vehicula quam. Curabitur vel tortor vitae pede imperdiet ultrices. Sed tortor.
 </header><!-- .header-->

 <main class="content">
  <strong>Content:</strong> Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. Quisque vitae pede. Nam et augue. Sed a elit. Ut vel massa. Suspendisse nibh pede, ultrices vitae, ultrices nec, mollis non, nibh. In sit amet pede quis leo vulputate hendrerit. Cras laoreet leo et justo auctor condimentum. Integer id enim. Suspendisse egestas, dui ac egestas mollis, libero orci hendrerit lacus, et malesuada lorem neque ac libero. Morbi tempor pulvinar pede. Donec vel elit.
 </main><!-- .content -->

</div><!-- .wrapper -->

<footer class="footer">
 <strong>Footer:</strong> Mus elit Morbi mus enim lacus at quis Nam eget morbi. Et semper urna urna non at cursus dolor vestibulum neque enim. Tellus interdum at laoreet laoreet lacinia lacinia sed Quisque justo quis. Hendrerit scelerisque lorem elit orci tempor tincidunt enim Phasellus dignissim tincidunt. Nunc vel et Sed nisl Vestibulum odio montes Aliquam volutpat pellentesque. Ut pede sagittis et quis nunc gravida porttitor ligula.
</footer><!-- .footer -->

</body>
</html>
```